# Open a html page for printing

Tags: meteor

This Meteor client code works on Android Chrome fine. It opens the print dialog and print. It also opens the dialog print on MacBook Chrome, but the dialog page failed to show the content of the html. It needs to work on all devices.
When tried on Mac Safari, the browser flickers but failed to open the printer dialog all together.

Any idea how to show the content so that it does not print a blank page once the Print button is hit? thx

**edit**
It worked find on Windows Firefox.
It worked fine on Mac Chrome after removing the `return true`

It failed to work on Mac Safari.

```
    print: () => {
      let data = $('form').html();
      let w = window.open();  //opens in a new tab
      w.document.write('<html><head><title>Print Document</title>');
      w.document.write('</head><body>');
      w.document.write(data);
      w.document.write('</body></html>');

      w.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
      w.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
      w.print();
      w.close();
      return true;
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `setTimeout`:

```
 setTimeout(function(){
    w.focus();
 },2000);
```

Comment: This solution stops the page from loading up in the browser.

Comment: return true not needed

Comment: Removing `return true` fixed the issue with the Mac Chrome. but Mac Safari still flickers and failed to open the printer dialogue.

Comment: happy for that you are in one step upward

Comment: @Ialithkumar The page is produced dynamically with Meteor framework, it has lots of js and some images... so it is a bit complex, i.e. not a simple page.